# resize datagrid based on a screen resolution

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a nested datagrid on my screen.It does not take the whole space of my window.I have set the height and width of the datagrids. My problem is when that the datagrid size is the same on every screen resolution. How can I make it to adjust based on a resolution?
Can I do that somehow with the MinWidth and MaxWidth? or something like that?If I use SizeToContent,it does not maximize the window.

This is how the window should look
[image: This is how the window should look]
This is XAML definition for the grid and main table:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="209*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Name="tabela" Grid.Row="1" Width="1100" Height="700" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" AlternatingRowBackground="#eeeeee" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="tabela_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged" SelectionChanged="tabela_SelectionChanged" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="tabela"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              AlternatingRowBackground="#eeeeee"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="tabela_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged" 
              SelectionChanged="tabela_SelectionChanged" >
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

If you want your controls to resize according to their parent size (in this case it's your window), you can't set `Width` and `Height` at all. You can play with `MinWidth`, `MinHeight`, `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` if you want to, but in most cases, controls just stretch to take all available space. It's being set by `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` and `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` (in most cases those are default values, but I have set them explicitly in case you have it overriden somewhere else).

Another thing is if you set up a `Grid` with `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions`, don't do it if you are not using it. Just `Grid` is enough to be a container for a single control such as `DataGrid`. If you do set `Rows` and `Columns`, you can set their `Width` and `Height` to one of three value types:

- Exact value (e.g. 100)
- `Auto` - `Rows` or `Columns` will resize to take just as much space as their content
- `*` - this is a proportion marking, so setting star width to one column while you have three of them, will make this column to take all available space. On the other hand if you have two columns and you set `Width="*"` to the first one and `Width="2*"` to the second one, all available space will be divided into 3 parts and the first column will get 1/3 of it and the second one 2/3 (you can play with it however you want).